# How to handle events of a Frame Scrollbar?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two frames on a userform and there's a picture on each frame, the pictures can be wider or higher than the frames and that's why I need the scrollbars. What I want to do is that when/if the user needs to use the horizontal scrollbar on say frame 1, the horizontal scrollbar on frame2 should take the same value.

I was looking for something like:

```
Frame1.HorizontalScrollBar.Value
```

But that's not a property of the scrollbars. I found in a website that the event handler of a frame's scrollbar is:

```
Private Sub Frame1_Scroll(ByVal ActionX As MSForms.fmScrollAction, ByVal ActionY As MSForms.fmScrollAction, ByVal RequestDx As Single, ByVal RequestDy As Single, ByVal ActualDx As MSForms.ReturnSingle, ByVal ActualDy As MSForms.ReturnSingle) 

End sub
```

And I tried it but I can't figure out how to assign those values to the second horizontal scrollbar when the event is fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place all of the following into the userform code module:

```
Private bIgnore As Boolean


Private Sub Frame1_Scroll(ByVal ActionX As MSForms.fmScrollAction, ByVal ActionY As MSForms.fmScrollAction, ByVal RequestDx As Single, ByVal RequestDy As Single, ByVal ActualDx As MSForms.ReturnSingle, ByVal ActualDy As MSForms.ReturnSingle)
    If Not bIgnore Then
        bIgnore = 1
        Frame2.ScrollLeft = Frame1.ScrollLeft + ActualDx
        bIgnore = 0
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Frame2_Scroll(ByVal ActionX As MSForms.fmScrollAction, ByVal ActionY As MSForms.fmScrollAction, ByVal RequestDx As Single, ByVal RequestDy As Single, ByVal ActualDx As MSForms.ReturnSingle, ByVal ActualDy As MSForms.ReturnSingle)
    If Not bIgnore Then
        bIgnore = 1
        Frame1.ScrollLeft = Frame2.ScrollLeft + ActualDx
        bIgnore = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: this assumes your frames are named Frame1 and Frame2 and that both frames have been configured with the same ScrollWidth value.

Comment: Thank you!! Thank you very much :D Sorry for the late thanks, I was trying to figure out what the bIgnore did.. I had'nt thought that when moving one scrollbar the other one moved too and both events would fire creating a conflict. That was the part I was missing. Thank you very much again @ExcelHero